# How to fix operands of different shapes?

Tags: python

```
nonlin = flux_2/fit_2 

polyfit_function = np.polyfit(flux_1[i,j,:], nonlin, 3, full=True) 
print(polyfit_function)

fit=np.polyval(polyfit_function,np.arange(np.min(flux_1),np.max(flux_1)))

plt.plot(flux_1[i,j,:], nonlin,'.')
plt.plot(np.arange(np.min(flux_1),np.max(flux_1)), polyfit_function)
plt.show()
```

The error that occurs is in the `np.polyval` function:

```
val(p, x)
    679         y = NX.zeros_like(x)
    680     for i in range(len(p)):
--> 681         y = y * x + p[i]
    682     return y
    683 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (24479,) (4,)
```

Thought that the error may have been due to using numpy arrays however converting to python lists didn't help.

Help please :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `full=True` returns a 5-tuple where only the first value is the answer. The other four are, according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html.),

> diagnostic information from the singular value decomposition,

whatever that means.

So either don't set `full=True`, or do something like

```
polyfit_function, *diagnostics = np.polyfit(flux_1[i,j,:], nonlin, 3, full=True)
```